# Kafka reading same messages from different partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Hi I have created a kafka listener in spring boot, But it is reading same messages from different partitions.

We are reading as a batch and acknowledging manually once the processing is over.

I have set a batch list size as 10 and wait time as 2s.

**configurations**

```
enable.auto.commit = false

consumer type as BATCH

AckMode as MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId= "myGroupId") public void listen(Listg<MyObject>data,Acknowledge acknowledge) { //processing ........... acknowledge.acknowledge() }
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Why would it not read messages from different partitions?

Comment: If your consumer read same messages from different partitions, then there should be a problem in producer side not consumer side.

Comment: Is it beacuse producer is pushing same messages to different partitions? Do we need to have a key before pushing messages to kafka topics.

Comment: Producer will push messages in different partitions but will always push messages with the same key in the same partition. However the producer doesn't push the same message more than once (in more than one partition).